# Magento2 - After upgrading webshop redirects to localhost

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I have just updated my magento website from version 2.1.7 to 2.1.8.

I have used the following commands:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.8 --no-update
(pass required update version number)

composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

After the above commands were executed, the frontend and the backend are redirected to localhost.

I have checked the core_config_data in the database, all the base urls are set correctly...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When the default `base_url` and `unsecure_base_url` are set to `{{base_url}}` or something similar the default fallback for this is `localhost`....

I don't know why this occured after the upgrade because before the update it was working fine... Why, I don't know...

Comment: You might need to check your .htaccess file, it gets over-written on the updates, so need to add in that line that redirects to the correct store view.

Answer (score 1):

Updating/Upgrading to Magento 2.1.8 (via composer)

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.8 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/cache/* var/page_cache
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why would you delete the folders `di, generation, view_preprocessed, cache and page_cache`? When this also gets deleted with the `setup:upgrade` command... Also after the deletion of those folders you flush and clean cache with the cli commands, but the cache is already gone due to the removed directories.. Just a tought :)